# How to reference categories table in products table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

[image]

I am using **modified preorder traversal algorithm** to store product categories in database (like image shown above). But i don't understand how to reference it in my **products** table. Here is my **products** table

```
product
id |  name        | supplier         | price | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  T shirts    | Rana Enterprises | 200   | Run faster than light!
2  |  Shoes       | RS Shirts        | 100   | If you're going to San Francisco...
```

Tell me how to link my categories table to **products** table ?